# Which column to use for ordering change data read from change tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, replication, change-data-capture

Should I rely on seqval for ordering change data captured from change tables in SQL Server, documentation provides contradictory statements in two places. If not, is there any option?

If we check [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#table-returned), it says for __$seqval

> Sequence value used to order changes to a row within a transaction.

And here in [cdc.<capture_instance>_CT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), it is mentioned for __$seqval:

> Sequence of the operation as represented in the transaction log. Should not be used for ordering. Instead, use the __$command_id column.

I believe both these __$seqval are same as `fn_cdc_get_all_changes` function reads from `cdc.<capture_instance>_CT` table. I would have used `__$command_id` if it was returned from `fn_cdc_get_all_changes` function as reading from system tables directly is [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=We%20recommend%20that,Expand%20table).

Comment: Perhaps consider the effort it takes to write vs. the effort it takes to read. Also, with proper indexing, sorting when reading should be manageable. I'm not sure about the size of the data; that might be a thing to consider. Set your primary key soft order in alignment with that.

Comment: @WalterVerhoeven I have no control over the data in table. I just want to replicate the databases. Table can have or not have index / primary key, just want to use a column from fn_cdc_get_all_changes for ordering

Comment: I read the docs as if you use cdc.<capture_instance>_CT then you should convert your code to use _$command_id but if you use  cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance> then you should continue to use __$seqval